# one-to-many without foreign key in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, hibernate, hsqldb

I have 2 classes Meal and Day.
One Day can have several Meals and one Meal can be served on several Days.
I store a Day object with all the meals from a day.
And a Meal object with no attribute of the type Day.
Code looks as follows:

```
public class Day {
Date date;
private Map<Meal, List<Integer>> mealsLines;

public Day() {
} ....
}


public class Meal implements java.io.Serializable {
private long id;
private String name;

public Meal() {
} ....


<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="data.Day" table="DAY">
    <id name="date" type="java.sql.Date" access="field">
        <column name="DATE" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <map name="mealsLines" table="MEAL" lazy="true" access="field">
        <key>
            <column name="DATE" />
        </key>
        <map-key type="data.Meal"></map-key>
        <one-to-many class="data.Meal" />
    </map>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>


<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="data.Meal" table="MEAL">
    <id name="id" type="long">
        <column name="ID" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
        <column name="NAME" />
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

So now with these maps I get two Tables:
Meal
ID NAME ----> DATE  <---- wrong

Day
DATE

Which is nonsense because one meal can be severed on more than one day.
I dont want a foreign key in meal. How can I realise this?
Thanks

Comment: _Why_ don't you want foreign keys? Are you perhaps confusing the database-level concept of a foreign key with the object-level concept of a relationship and a reference to another object? They are not the same, and that is _exactly_ the purpose of Hibernate...to allow you to keep the concepts separate and map between them.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. By having one meal on many days and many meals on one day, you *must* have a many-to-many relationship.

In order to do this, you *must* have an associative table between the Meal and the Day tables.

By default, Hibernate will try to use Foreign Keys on the tables if it can because it allows the database to help ensure data consistency and correctness, and is also often faster due to implicit indices that most relational DBs create with foreign keys.

Comment: Take a read through the hibernate user guide: http://www.hibernate.org/docs. Specifically, this section: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/associations.html#assoc-bidirectional-join-m2m

Comment: Okay I tried to do it with a many-to-many map now but I cant figure out how to write it down. Do I have to write 2 <map>-mappings in each mappingfile? And how do I map the Meals on the days since I have no attribute in meals that stores that information.

Comment: If you don't have an attribute in meals indicating the days, why do you care that a meal can be in many days? A simple one-to-many relationship (one day, many meals) will work.

Comment: Well yes but the I have a foreign key in meal which would be wrong? How do I create a one-to-many relation via a new table?

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking is a one-to-many , while from your description it appears that many to many relation is required. The way you could implement is by creating another mapping class/table which will map foreign keys of other two tables.

```
MEAL
╔════════════╗
║ ID* | NAME ║
╠════════════╣
║ 1   | M1   ║
║ 2   | M2   ║
╚════════════╝

DAY
╔════════════╗
║ ID* | DESC ║
╠════════════╣
║ D1  | aa   ║
║ D2  | bb   ║
╚════════════╝

MEAL_DAY_MAPPING

╔══════════╦═════════╦══════════════════╗
║ MEAL_ID* ║ DAY_ID* ║ MEAL_DAY_DETAILS ║
╠══════════╬═════════╬══════════════════╣
║        1 ║ D1      ║ XXX              ║
║        1 ║ D2      ║ YYY              ║
║        2 ║ D1      ║ ZZZ              ║
╚══════════╩═════════╩══════════════════╝

* indicates PK
```

Ref

- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#d0e11567
- http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation

Comment: Note: tables generated using http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html